# I have a problem with tis array of struct please help me create a tag also

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, erc-20, web3-providers

```
struct people {
uint256 favouriteNumber;
string name; // now we have a new type of people,
}
//and the much better way to create a list of people is to add a data structure called an ARRAY of struct
//uint256[] public favouriteNumberList;
People[] public people;
```

```
               AND THIS IS THE ERROR THAT IT BRING
```

from solidity:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
--> contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:17:5:
|
17 | People[] public people;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: The previous declaration is here:
--> contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:11:5:
|
11 | struct people {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

from solidity:
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
--> contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:17:5:
|
17 | People[] public people;
| ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```
struct People {
uint256 favouriteNumber;
string name; // now we have a new type of people,
}
//and the much better way to create a list of people is to add a data structure called an ARRAY of struct
//uint256[] public favouriteNumberList;
People[] public people;
```